# How to divide Bootstrap row to same size five columns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to divide bootstrap row into five columns but there are 12 units to the device. How can I divide it into five?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-*-2` to each column

Also use `justify-content-center` to center the columns (because the one unnecessary column(12/2=6))

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      3
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you only need to set `col` for each one